# Selinium is installed but cannot be imported or used. ImportError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: selenium, importerror

I have installed Selenium.When i try to run the tests it complains of ImportError: No module named 'selenium'.
The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and python version 3.4 (via virtualenv).

Installation of selenium:

```
(p_live) user@ubuntu14.04 LTS:~/sites/site.com/source$ sudo pip3 install selenium
[sudo] password for karthi:
Downloading/unpacking selenium
  Downloading selenium-2.53.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (884kB): 884kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: selenium
Successfully installed selenium
Cleaning up...
```

Selenium is installed as seen from whereis:

```
(p_live) user@ubuntu14.04 LTS:~/sites/site.com/source$ whereis selenium
selenium: /usr/local/selenium
```

For some strange reason find doesnot spot selenium

```
(p_live) user@ubuntu14.04 LTS:~/sites/site.com/source$ find selenium
find: `selenium': No such file or directory
```

Alternatively tried importing it.

```
(p_live) user@ubuntu14.04 LTS:~/sites/site.com/source$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'selenium'
>>>
```

When it is installed what is the reason i am not able to import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sudo` to install `selenium` into your virtual environment:

```
(p_live) $ pip3 install selenium
```

Comment: oofs..sudo was accidental. Thanks.